# Is there any way in pyspark to pick any particular value from each column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark df with columns A B C like below. A is the primary key

```
A  B     C
1 true  false 
1 false true 
2 false false 
2 false true
```

For a particular primary key if B has true in any rows, the final df should have true. Similarily for column C. The final DF will have only 1 record for 1 primary key.

The output df I want is something like below

```
A  B     C
1 true  true
2 false true
```

Currently I am trying to create seperate dfs for A B and A C, selecting the record in which B is having true and C is having true, then creating a final df joining dfs A B and A C based on primary key A. Could you please suggest any alternative way that I can use here?

Answer (score 0):

Since `True > False`, you can take a `max` of the boolean values for each primary key (considering the data type of the field in `boolean`).

```py
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('a'). \
    agg(func.max('b').alias('b'),
        func.max('c').alias('c')
        ). \
    show()

# +---+-----+----+
# |  a|    b|   c|
# +---+-----+----+
# |  1| true|true|
# |  2|false|true|
# +---+-----+----+
```

Comment: Can I also use a order by on the same? If I have a column Date D, I should only create the final df based on the latest date.

Comment: I got a way where I am grouping it on A and D, then using window function and rownumber() to only select the latest value in D. It looks like this
df1.groupBy('a','d').agg(F.max('b').alias('b'),F.max('c').alias('c')).withColumn("rownumber",F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("a",).orderBy(d.desc()))).where("rownumber=1").drop("rownumber").show()... Is there any other way to reduce complexity.

Comment: @AmaravathiSatya - seems okay to me.

Comment: Hey Again, Can you please let me know how to do the same in pandas if you have any idea. just need to get A  B     C
1 true  true
2 false true

Comment: @AmaravathiSatya - that'd be a basic `groupby` on `'a'` with `max()` operator for `['b', 'c']`